# Using Google Sign-In on my website, how can I sign the user out?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-oauth, google-openid

I seem to have a working solution, but it's unbelievably complicated!

First, I need to download some code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Second and third, I need to download the `auth2` module.
After that I need to provide client_app_id to asynchronously get an auth object instance:

```
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '__________.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        });
    });
```

Fourth, fuh, I can finally log out:

```
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut().then(function () {
                  ...
            });
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can this be done easier? I have found some docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners) and [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#auth-setup)

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. It's complicated but all necessary steps.

A slight optimization is that you can request something smaller than `platform.js`. Namely `https://apis.google.com/js/auth2:signin2.js`

What I do is set a callback too, so something like this:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{{ OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID }}">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/auth2:signin2.js?onload=googleAPILoaded"></script>
<script>
window.googleAPILoaded = function() {
  gapi.auth2.init();
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
  .then(function() {
      this.signOut().then(serverSignout);
  });
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: auth2:signin2.js file has 15K, while packages.js has 16K. auth2:signin2.js shows me 307 Internal redirect, so potentially it gets downloaded longer

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use [Google's Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) template to initialize the login & grant of permissions process in a slightly more elegant manner:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{{ OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID }}">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="google-signin-button"
     class="g-signin2"
     data-width="170"
     data-height="30"
     data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
     data-onfailure="onSignInFailure">
</div>
```

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}

function onSignOut(){
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut();
}
```

Comment: I know this, but because I perform redirect from login page (where gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance variable existed) to application page. Probably this step is wrong, Google suggested I should have single page for everything. Do you also think login page is spmething unnecessary?